# Proving Trigonometric identity

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove this identities?

$(\sin \theta +  \cos \theta)^2 = 1 + \sin 2\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand:

$$ \sin^2 + \cos^2 \theta + 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$$

Now use these identites:

$$ \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$$

and,

$$ 2 \sin x \cos x  = \sin 2x$$